# Stream of Unicode Code Points from Bytes in C?

Tags: c, unicode, icu

I'm writing an HTML parser in C, and am looking to correctly follow [the W3C guidelines on parser implementation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing). One of the key points is that the parser operates on a stream of Unicode Code Points rather than bytes, which makes sense.

Basically, then, given a buffer **of known character encoding** (I will either be given an explicit input encoding, or will use the HTML5 prescan algorithm to make a good guess), what's the best way in C — ideally cross-platform, but sticking to UNIX is fine — to iterate over an equivalent sequence of Unicode Code Points?

Is alloc'ing a few reasonably-sized buffers and using `iconv` the way to go? Should I be looking at ICU? The macros like `U16_NEXT` seem to be well-suited to my task, but the ICU documentation is incredibly long-winded, and it's a little hard to see exactly how to glue things together.

Comment: `iconv` seems like a good start. It's conceptually simple and widely available.

Comment: OK, I'll give `iconv` a try. Would you say it makes most sense to convert to UTF-32? Even though it's arguably a nearly-useless encoding, that would mean every 4 bytes would exactly represent a Unicode Code Point.

Comment: Yes, indeed. UTF-32 is a perfectly fine encoding.

Comment: UCS-4/UTF-32 is fine. 1) it's the only fixed size encoding that covers all code points (2 bytes are just not enough). 2) for example `glibc` uses 4 byte (double word) representation for the `wchar_t` type anyway. 3) memory usually isn't problem these days. 5) fixed-size encoding has some speed and memory allocation advantages.

Comment: Personally I would suggest UTF-8, as UTF-32 is overkill for most HTML documents, that are primarily ASCII text. It will also simplify integration with other C libraries.

Answer (score 2):

ICU is a good choice. I used it with C++ and liked it a lot. I am quite sure you get similar thought-through APIs in C as well.

Not totally the same but somewhat related might be this [tutorial](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general) that explains how to perform streaming/incremental transliteration (the difficulty in this case is that the "cursor" may be *inside* a code point sometimes).

Answer (score 2):

The following will decode a code point and return how much to increment the string by (how much was "chewed").  Note that xs_utf16 is an unsigned short. More info: http://sree.kotay.com/2006/12/unicode-is-pain-in.html

```
enum
{
    xs_UTF_Max          = 0x0010FFFFUL,
    xs_UTF_Replace      = 0x0000FFFDUL,
    xs_UTF16_HalfBase   = 0x00010000UL,
    xs_UTF16_HighStart  = 0x0000D800UL,
    xs_UTF16_HighEnd    = 0x0000DBFFUL,
    xs_UTF16_LowStart   = 0x0000DC00UL,
    xs_UTF16_LowEnd     = 0x0000DFFFUL,
    xs_UTF16_MaxUCS2    = 0x0000FFFFUL,
    xs_UTF16_HalfMask   = 0x000003FFUL,
    xs_UTF16_HalfShift  = 10
};


int32 xs_UTF16Decode (uint32 &code, const xs_utf16* str, int32 len, bool strict)
{
          if (str==0||len==0)          {code=0; return 0;}

          uint32 c1 = str[0];

          //note: many implementations test from HighStart to HighEnd,
          //                 this may be a partial code point, and is incorrect(?)
          //                 trivial checking should exclude the WHOLE surrogate range
          if (c1<xs_UTF16_HighStart || c1>xs_UTF16_LowEnd)          return 1;
                             //really an error if we're starting in the low range

          //surrogate pair
          if (len<=1 || str[1]==0)                                  {code=xs_UTF_Replace; return strict ? 0 : 1;} //error
          uint32 c2 = str[1];
          code = ((c1-xs_UTF16_HighStart)<<xs_UTF16_HalfShift) + (c2-xs_UTF16_LowStart) + xs_UTF16_HalfBase;

          if (strict==false)                                        return 2;

          //check for errors
          if (c1>=xs_UTF16_LowStart && c1<=xs_UTF16_LowEnd)         {code=xs_UTF_Replace; return 0;} //error
          if (c2<xs_UTF16_LowStart  || c2>xs_UTF16_LowEnd)          {code=xs_UTF_Replace; return 0;} //error
          if (code>xs_UTF_Max)                                      {code=xs_UTF_Replace; return 0;} //error

          //success
          return 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things may be of interest to you:

1. [Markus Kuhn Unicode tutorials](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html)
2. [lib9](http://golang.org/src/lib9/utf/), the utf library from Plan9, the Os which the inventors of UTF were working on.